# Disable proximity sensor on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, calls, screen, xiaomi, proximity-sensor

My Xiaomi phone proximity sensor was broken, it is giving false result, most of the time it think it is blocked when it was not, and its value keeps changing. This affect phone call because the screen is turned off until the phone call is over or I force reboot the phone. I have disabled the screen off during call at Apps/System app settings/Call settings/Incoming call Settings to workaround this problem.

However, it looks like WhatsApp is not affected by these settings. My screen is turned off for the entire duration of WhatsApp calls, I can't even end calls due to this, the only way to escape is to force reboot the phone or wait for the other person to end the call.

Is there any way to set WhatsApp to keep the screen on during phone calls? I haven't found the answer on Google, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to disable proximity sensor](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/34700/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen turns off during call due to problem with proximity sensor - Xperia Z3 compact](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133160/screen-turns-off-during-call-due-to-problem-with-proximity-sensor-xperia-z3-co)